# MySQL Joins and nulls

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, left-join

I've cruised the internets for hours and can't seem to figure this one out!

I have some tables:

### ResourceShort

<kbd>idResourceShort</kbd><kbd>value</kbd>      <kbd>idLanguage</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>                         <kbd>Play</kbd>        <kbd>1</kbd>                 
<kbd>2</kbd>                         <kbd>Easy</kbd>       <kbd>1</kbd>                 
<kbd>...</kbd>                        <kbd>...</kbd>                               
<kbd>257</kbd>                     <kbd>Jouer</kbd>      <kbd>2</kbd>

### ResourceOriginal

<kbd>idResourceOriginal</kbd><kbd>value</kbd>      <kbd>context</kbd>                    
<kbd>1</kbd>                             <kbd>Play</kbd>        <kbd>button to play game</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>                             <kbd>Easy</kbd>       <kbd>ai mode</kbd>                   
<kbd>...</kbd>                            <kbd>...</kbd>            <kbd>...</kbd>                             
<kbd>257</kbd>                         <kbd>Game</kbd>     <kbd>NULL</kbd>

### ResourceOriginal_ResourceShort

<kbd>idResourceOriginal</kbd><kbd>idResourceShort</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>                             <kbd>1</kbd>                              
<kbd>1</kbd>                             <kbd>257</kbd>                          
<kbd>...</kbd>                            <kbd>...</kbd>                             
<kbd>2</kbd>                             <kbd>2</kbd>

### Language

<kbd>idLanguage</kbd><kbd>name</kbd>   
<kbd>1</kbd>                 <kbd>English</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>                 <kbd>French</kbd>
<kbd>3</kbd>                 <kbd>Italian</kbd>  
<kbd>...</kbd>                <kbd>...</kbd>

I'm looking to retrieve all values per language, like so:

### Translations

<kbd>Language Name</kbd><kbd>context</kbd>                    <kbd>value</kbd>                    
<kbd>English</kbd>               <kbd>button to play game</kbd><kbd>Play</kbd>                      
<kbd>French</kbd>               <kbd>buton to play game</kbd> <kbd>Jouer</kbd>                    
<kbd>Italian</kbd>                 <kbd>button to play game</kbd><kbd>NULL</kbd>

I currently have a query like so:

> SELECT Language.name, ResourceOriginal.context, ResourceShort.value
>   FROM ResourceShort 
>   JOIN ResourceOriginal_ResourceShort ON ResourceOriginal_ResourceShort.idResourceShort = ResourceShort.idResourceShort
>   JOIN ResourceOriginal ON ResourceOriginal_ResourceShort.idResourceOriginal = ResourceOriginal.idResourceOriginal
>   JOIN Language ON Language.idLanguage = ResourceShort.idLanguage
>   WHERE ResourceOriginal.value LIKE 'Play

...it's only yielding results for English and French - I want to include nulls too.

Note: In ResourceShort, the row doesn't exist for Italian - the translation does not yet exist.

Essentially, I want to list all the translation in the Database for a certain word.

If it's not clear:

- ResourceOriginal is the original string
- ResourceShort are the translations for the original string, including in the Original language. (Yes, data is redundant but makes for less complex querying).

Any help is greatly appreciated and a solution will get my vote!

Thanks y'all!

Comment: sqlfiddle for DB creation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/29384

Comment: Please add sample data for the tables provided here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/846e4/1

Comment: So fresh so clean! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d275/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'm understanding what you want returned; the query below should get you that.

It looks like you want to get all rows from the `ResourceOriginal` table that match some predicate, in your example, with `value` of `'Play'`.

Then, for each row in `Language` (if you have e.g. English, French,  and Italian), you want to lookup the corresponding value.  The "trick" we use in the query is a CROSS JOIN. That get's us a matching row for each language. So, if we return one row from ResourceOriginal, and we get three rows from Language, we'll get three rows back.

With that set, we can do lookups of the actual value. But we need to make these lookups to be OUTER joins, so that we don't eliminate any rows. We want to keep the rows we generated for each language, even when we don't find a match. We'll just return a NULL when no matching row is found.

Something like this:

```
SELECT l.name
     , o.context
     , s.value
  FROM Language l 
 CROSS 
  JOIN ResourceOriginal o
  LEFT
  JOIN ResourceOriginal_ResourceShort r
    ON r.idResourceOriginal = o.idResourceOriginal
  LEFT
  JOIN ResourceShort s
    ON s.idResourceShort = r.idResourceShort
   AND s.idLanguage = l.idLanguage
 WHERE o.value LIKE 'Play'
```

---

NOTE: Because this is doing OUTER joins to preserve nulls, and because there are multiple rows in `RO_RS` that are related to a row in `RO`, we get multiple rows.

This could be avoided if the data model was slightly different. If the RO_RS table included the idLanguage value (so an appropriate predicate could be included in the JOIN clause). Or, if the RO_RS table was eliminated entirely, then the RS table could have a direct foreign key to the RO table.

We could monkey with a GROUP BY and a MAX aggregate around value... but that doesn't appropriately handle the more general case, allowed by the model... that is, for two or more rows in RS for the same language, related to the same RO.  (That RO_RS table allows for a many-to-many,)

Note that the data model allows for two (or more) `RS` of the same language for any given `RO`.

Consider if these rows were also added:

```
RS
  258, 'bazinga', 3
  259, 'booyah' , 3

RO_RS
  1, 258
  1, 259
```

That leads to adding these rows to the resultset.

```
language   context    value
--------   -------    -------
Italian    button...  bazinga  
Italian    button...  booyah
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. Thank you so very much! You explained all this in a clear and precise manner. I appreciate it! What would your suggestion be, as to having the idLanguage key in the RO_RS table as opposed to eliminating the RO_RS table and having the idLanguage key in the RS table directly? I was trying to normalize the data but I guess I need to get a better understanding first! We're looking to CRUDS the data and naturally have no duplicates. Thanks again for all your input!

Comment: @user3083452: Thanks for the feedback! Glad you found this helpful. Personally, I'd ask the question, can a given `RO` have more than one row in `RS` for a given language? If there's only one, I'd eliminate the RO_RS table, and put the `idRO` foreign key in the `RS` table. If I needed a many-to-many relationship between RO and RS, I'd put the idLanguage column in the RO_RS relationship table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `OR  ro.value IS NULL` and `RIGHT JOIN Language` to get all languages

```
SELECT 
  l.name,
  ro.context,
  rs.value 
FROM
  ResourceShort rs 
  RIGHT JOIN `Language` l 
    ON l.idLanguage = rs.idLanguage 
  LEFT JOIN ResourceOriginal_ResourceShort rors 
    ON rors.idResourceShort = rs.idResourceShort 
  LEFT JOIN ResourceOriginal ro 
    ON rors.idResourceOriginal = ro.idResourceOriginal 
WHERE ro.value LIKE 'Play%' 
  OR ro.value IS NULL
```

### [**See Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d275/7)

Comment: I realized I omitted some information in the ResourceShort table:

Comment: I realized I omitted some information in the ResourceShort table: the row with the italian value/translation for "Play" does not exist in the table (it has not been translated for that language, for example).

ResourceOriginal.value will never be null, it is the original string (first thing created) - and ResouceShort.value will never be null either as it won't exist in the DB unless the translation has come in. We're testing ResourceOrignal.value b/c looking up "%car%" in ResourceOriginal (English values) is different from looking up "%car%" in Italian.

Comment: 'English','Takes you to the game','Play!'
'French','Takes you to the game','Jouer!'
'English','Start the game','PLAY!'
'French','Start the game','JOUER !'

Comment: @user3083452 can you add the sql fiddle with sample datasets here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to originally put NULLs in the table in ResourceShort? That's what I'm looking for, for the Query to produce nulls using what's in the database.

Comment: WORKING SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d275/1 - Thanks! I didn't know about this tool!

Comment: If you execute the SELECT statement... I am expecting a third row with Italian | button to play a game | NULL - does this make any sense? Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3083452 [**See fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d275/7) and see my updated query

Answer (score 1):

Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN for ResourceOriginal.

Comment: This SQLFiddle has it all in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d275/1 A simple LEFT OUTER JOIN is not the solution unfortunately... any other thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Your data structures aren't making sense to me. Try to eliminate redundancy. Combine your ResourceShort and ResourceOriginal tables and eliminate the ResourceOriginal_ResourceShort table. For record 257, why is value "Jouer" in ResourceShort and "GAME" in ResourceOriginal? Do you mean "Play"? And why is the context "null" for that record? Try to be clear about what these fields mean. I don't know what you're trying to do with the data structures as you have them now.